# Partition function for specific potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

Considering a gas of N classical particles, in the canonical essemble, with  the following potential:

$$ V(|\overrightarrow{r_i} - \overrightarrow{r_j}|) = \alpha |\overrightarrow{r_i} - \overrightarrow{r_j}|^{- \mu}$$

Im having trouble computing the position integral in the partition function:

$$ Z= \frac{1}{h^3N!} \int d^{3N}xd^{3N}P \exp \left[ - \beta \left( \sum_i \frac{P_i^2}{2m} + \sum_{i<j} V(|\overrightarrow{r_i} - \overrightarrow{r_j}|) \right) \right]$$

For the momenta, we find the usual Gaussian integral:

$$ \int d^{3N}P \exp \left[ - \beta \left( \sum_i \frac{P_i^2}{2m} \right) \right] = \left( \frac{2 \pi m}{\beta} \right)^{3N/2}$$

, but how do I work out the positions integral?

$$ \int d^{3N}x \exp \left[ - \beta \left( \sum_{i<j} V(|\overrightarrow{r_i} - \overrightarrow{r_j}|) \right) \right] = \int d^{N} \overrightarrow{r} \exp \left[ - \beta \left(   \sum_{i<j}  \alpha |\overrightarrow{r_i} - \overrightarrow{r_j}|^{- \mu}  \right) \right] =?$$

Comment: Apart from certain special cases, in general the position integral can not be done exactly and one has to reply on various approximate methods. Any graduate-level statistical mechanics textbook should have a chapter on this topic.